# How can i do a crosstab with weigths in another column?

Tags: python, pandas

Hello I have the following code, in order to do a matrix of adjacency, but I have the weight by peer in another column, how can do the adjacency matrix in panda with this data?

Current code:

```
ady = pd.read_csv("edges.csv", sep=',')[['Source', 'Target', 'weight']]
ady['weight'] = pd.to_numeric(ady['weight'])
ady = pd.crosstab(ady.Source, ady.Target, ady.weight, aggfunc = sum)
```

Data:

```
Source, Target, weight
a,b,2
a,c,1
b,a,2
b,b,1
c,a,1
```

Expected data:

```
  a,b,c
a 0,2,1
b 2,1,0
c 1,0,0
```

dtypes:

```
ady.dtypes
Source     object
Target     object
weight    float64
```

Original data:
https://pastebin.com/Y55a64yz

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: kindly post your expected outcome

Comment: Can you explain why your solution `pd.crosstab(ady.Source, ady.Target, ady.weight, aggfunc = sum)` not working? Because with sample data get expected output.

Comment: Maybe is necessay change data for see problem of solution.

Comment: I get NaN, in all columns

Comment: with sample data solution failed also?

Comment: It's working perfectly fine for me.

Comment: I think it is because of the spaces in your columns. You may be getting all the data in `Source` column itself, and NaN in others. Try `sep=','` in `read_csv`

Comment: I think that error is another because the dtypes is float64, and happened the same with sep=','.

Comment: Did you control `print(adi)`? I suspect that columns `Target` and `Weight` only contain NaN values...

Comment: Updated!, there arent columnes when wheight is 0

Answer (score 0):

You could simply `pivot` the `adi` DataFrame:

```
adi.pivot(*adi.columns)
```

gives:

```
Target  a  b  c
Source         
a       0  2  1
b       2  1  0
c       1  0  0
```

Comment: Unfortunately problem is something else, so not dupe - https://stackoverflow.com/q/47152691/

Comment: this doesn't work, I triyed with ady=ady.pivot(*ady.columns) and without call to crosstab, and get NaN

Comment: @jezrael: No idea... But I prefere trying simple ways before wondering why more complex ones do not work.

Comment: @SergeBallesta - ya, I test original solution and for me working :(

Answer (score 0):

Finnaly I needed iterate over all peers in the data and set weight to 0.

```
ady = pd.read_csv("edges.csv", sep=',')[['Source', 'Target', 'weight']]
for i in ady['Source'].unique():
    for j in ady['Target'].unique():
        filter_a = ady['Source']==i
        filter_b = ady['Target']==j
        if ady[filter_a & filter_b]['weight'].shape == (0,):
            ady = ady.append({'Source':i, 'Target':j, 'weight':0 }, ignore_index=True)
```